# How can I correctly cast an array pointer?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I am trying to cast an array a pointer so I can add the first and second elements. Yet this only works in 32 bit but not in 64 bit? Why?

```
procedure Add(const A, B: Pointer);
var
  I, J: Integer;
begin
  I := PInteger(@A)^;
  J := PInteger(@B)^;
  WriteLn(I + J);
end;

procedure Test(const A);
begin
  Add(PPointer(@A)[0], PPointer(@A)[1]);
end;

var
  A: Array of Integer;
begin
  SetLength(A, 2);
  A[0] := 2;
  A[1] := 4;

  Test(A[0]);

  // 32 bit compiler prints 6!
  // 64 bit compiler prints 2!

  ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are 32 or 64 bits wide depending on the platform. `Integer` is always 32 bytes wide. Instead of casting to `PPointer` cast to `PInteger`.

You really want to be avoiding casting where possible since you lose type safety. As a consequence of this, your code has too much indirection, and is only really working by coincidence. Perhaps you wanted to do something like this:

```
procedure Add(A, B: Pointer);
begin
  WriteLn(PInteger(A)^ + PInteger(B)^);
end;

procedure Test(const A);
var
  P: PInteger;
begin
  P := PInteger(@A);
  Add(@P[0], @P[1]);
end;
```

Or maybe

```
procedure Add(A, B: Pointer);
begin
  WriteLn(PInteger(A)^ + PInteger(B)^);
end;

procedure Test(const A);
var
  P: PInteger;
begin
  P := PInteger(@A);
  Add(P, P + 1);
end;
```

Comment: Correct way `Add(@PInteger(@A)[0], @PInteger(@A)[1]);`

Comment: No. That's the way to do it for Int64 arrays on x86 and x64

Comment: It just doesn't work with PInteger. `{$IFDEF X64}@PInt64(A)[0], @PInt64(A)[1]{$ELSE}@PInteger(A)[0], @PInteger(A)[1]{$ENDIF}`

Comment: You no longer have an array of Integer now. Your array of strings is an array of pointers. So cast to NativeInt. But the casting looks very dubious.

Comment: Nope `PNativeInt` doesn't work either. Please provide a solution.

Comment: I no longer know what your question is. You are now talking about strings.